# Is there an iPhone dock with a headset jack?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know of a dock for an iPhone that has standard usb data/power, but also a headset jack (not just speaker / headphones output)?

Comment: So what you're looking for is an iPhone dock with either a headphone/microphone combo jack, or separate mic and headphone jacks?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the former.

Comment: Either version would be fine for me. My headset has two separate plugs. I use an adapter to connect it to iPhone.

Comment: After several Google searches it doesn't seem like such a dock exists. What are you trying to accomplish, and why can't you just plug into the iPhone headphone jack while docked?

Comment: Pretty simple goal... I want to make one connection instead of two when I sit down at my desk.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to use the mic on the headphones (ie., use your phone as a phone), or is this just for listening to audio? If the latter, I've got a few ideas. And btw, what adapter are you using to connect a two-plug headset to an iPhone? I've been looking forever for one that someone has actually successfully used.

Comment: @Dori: This should make it: http://www.showmecables.com/viewItem.asp?idProduct=8335
@Konstantin Komissarchik: As Kyle said, it seems you won't find one soon. Why not going for a bluetooth headset? It will be even one less connection :)

Comment: @Everybody Yeah I like the last suggestion, Bluetooth all the way. Go for a Jawbone or something that sits on the desk if you don't want to wear a headset.

Comment: @Ludo - I'll hand over my money when someone says, "I own this exact one and it works 100%." Lots of companies advertise stuff they claim works with iPhones, but much of it doesn't. And here's my thumbs-down on BT earpieces: I find them uncomfortable, with mediocre sound quality and lousy battery life. What I *really* want is an iPhone 4-compatible version of [this](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B002QQHSJM/), [this](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0000ALPBP/), or [this](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000095SB0).

Comment: Not interested for bluetooth for when i am at my desk. Also not interested in integrated speakers (GSM interference issues in speakers). Just want a simple dock like apple's universal dock, but with a headset jack rather than just a line a out. It seams like it should be possible. The dock connector pinout (http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Apple_iPod,_iPad_and_iPhone_dock) shows pins 5 and 6 carrying audio input.

Answer (score 7):

I wonder what is that for, if it's to connect to a stereo, the jack on the [Universal Dock](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC746LL/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) is more than enough.

[image]

If the idea is to use the phone to answer calls while in the dock, I would strongly suggest a Bluetooth set as that's what they are made for. [You will find plenty](http://store.apple.com/us/search?find=bluetooth+headset&mco=Nzc1MjMwNg) on the Apple Store as well.

Comment: The purpose is to connect a good quality wired headset for listening to music and taking calls. I am not interested in using a bluetooth headset while i am at my desk. It is a fine solution for when i am on the move, but when at my desk, i like better quality audio.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem you face here is the fact that you want to use your phone, as a phone, while in a dock.

First problem:
Many docks are "not compatible" with the iPhone, they don't have GSM noise filters on their speakers, so if you dock it and listen to music, you get that god awful chirping when the GSM radio starts going.

Second problem:
Those that are, make data connections, not line-out connections! The only way to fulfill this request is;

- if the chosen dock connects not only via data, but ALSO via the headphone jack, and;
- that connection is a triple-ring connection, just like the iPhone headphones. Note that you're highly unlikely to find this, because docks are for data/playing audio (which can be accomplished via the audio jack), the "dock your phone and use the computer as a gateway to phone functions" use case is, unfortunately, not present.

Third problem:
The iPhone is *too* smart. A while back I was driving with my phone plugged into a line-in port on my car (for music), and I was received a phone call. I had guests in the car, all friends, and figured I would just let the conversation take place via the car stereo, and turn on speaker so the other part could adequately hear me. No such luck. When not on speaker, the call came out of the ear piece only, when on speaker, the call came out of the speaker ports. The iPhone will only use the headphone port for a call if it has a microphone attached.

[BluePhone Elite](http://mirasoftware.com/BPE2/) was an option for this (with serious caveats), but it never had terribly good support for the iPhone. Only because of the limitations imposed by Apple. And, apparently BPE is dead now? What a shame. That was a good app for many many other phones.

I'm (unfortunately) very confident in saying that you will have a very hard time finding this dream product of yours, and you're better off simply plugging your own headset into the headphone port, or like balexandre suggested, pair a Bluetooth headset. A product like you want will invariably not pass Apple Certification, which means you will not easily find it in any mainstream store (not only Apple Stores, but BestBuy and it's ilk).

Comment: Re "first problem", I don't really need a dock with speakers. The purpose is to export sound to headphones.

Comment: Re "second problem", I am fairly certain that doc connector carries analog stereo out. It would be far to expensive for docks to decode digital sound otherwise. What I don't know is whether there is an analog mic in stream as well or if apple simply forgot to include it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment in "third problem" or your assertion that such product is impossible due to apple controls. I figure either apple failed to include analog mic in stream in the dock connector or the dock manufacturers prefer to focus on "bookshelf docks" and haven't really thought about "desk docks" usecases.

Comment: I figured you wanted to use it for calls, as well as music, that's what the third problem is regarding. The only other best suggestion I can give is to take your headset(s) into an Apple Store/shop that carries iPhone docks, and try them out.